# Nested Control Structures Grade average calculator

Tags: java

How can I make the numbers that are larger than 100 or smaller than 0 to not be added in the average? The script compiles and runs fine, but when I enter 101 it tells me the number is too large, but still takes its average. Thanks!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ExerciseSix
{
public static void main( String[] args )
{

    Scanner dylan = new Scanner(System.in);

    int gradeCounter;
    int total;
    int grade;
    double average;

    total = 0;
    gradeCounter = 0;

    System.out.println( "Enter a grade or -1 to quit: " );
    grade = dylan.nextInt();

    while ( grade != -1 )
    {  


        total = total + grade;
        gradeCounter = gradeCounter + 1;




        if( grade > 100 || grade < 0) {         

        if ( grade > 100 ) {
        System.out.println( "Number too large, enter a new number");            
        }

        if ( grade < 0 ) {
        System.out.println( "Number too small, enter a new number");
        }

        }




        System.out.println( "Enter grade or -1 to quit: ");
        grade = dylan.nextInt();



    }


    if ( gradeCounter != 0 )

    {


        average = (double) total / gradeCounter;


        System.out.printf( "Class average is %.2f", average );



    }

    else
        System.out.println( "No grades were entered" );

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Add `continue` to skip to the next loop iteration. Move the calculations below these checks so that if the checks fail the calculations aren't performed.

```
if ( grade > 100 ) {
    System.out.println( "Number too large, enter a new number");  
    continue;
}

if ( grade < 0 ) {
    System.out.println( "Number too small, enter a new number");
    continue;
}

total = total + grade;
gradeCounter = gradeCounter + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are averaging before you test the value. Put the averaging code in an else statement.

```
    if ( grade > 100 || grade < 0) {         
        if ( grade > 100 ) {
            System.out.println( "Number too large, enter a new number");            
        }
        if ( grade < 0 ) {
            System.out.println( "Number too small, enter a new number");
        }
    } else {
        total = total + grade;
        gradeCounter = gradeCounter + 1;
    }
```